# Filling up form with predefined data in others website form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to fill up form in another website which is not in my control. I have some datas filled in my website, I need to pass those data and fill the existing form in another website. Is it possible to fill the form using php, jquery?

For simplicity,
I want to redirect user after filling up form in my site abc.com save it in my database and redirect to external website xyz.com and fill the existing form there.

Comment: Nope it is not possible ... you want to hack their site ?

Comment: Nope I am not trying to hack the site. Just want to fill the data so that user won't have to fill the data again.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be to replicate their form 1:1 on your site and submit it using `<form action="their_form_url">`. This would work, however, only if they don't have [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) countermeasures in place (most sites don't, some do).

You will not be able to manipulate the form with JavaScript in pretty much any way unless the iframe target (i.e., their site) is in your domain.

If you only want to fill the data in without submitting, you are out of luck. Both JS and cookies follow the same-origin policy, which explicitly dictates defenses against this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the target website. If they pre-fill their form with $_GET data or $_POST data, you can just pass on that data. A good shot may be to try to post wrong data (like a wrong captcha value) manually and see how they fill their form again. Maybe you could use that in your favor.

Although, another possibility is to load their site in an iframe, and put the data with Javascript, by accessing the iframe code. I'm not sure about this, though. I just think it can be done. (Please correct me, if I'm wrong)

Comment: You're right. I couldn't recall why I haven't done that before. That is why.